# two frame navigation (first one add entry when second one navigate a page)

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

i have an application with main window that contain main frame . i navigate my pages in that frame . i handle my navigation in a static class that get the frame at start application and navigate pages in that.

one of my page has another frame in his content (name this frame second frame) so when the second frame navigate some thing (page or user control) in it ,my main frame automatically add a back entry to it. dunno what happen seems the navigation service is share between these two frame. and when i call GoBack function in main frame it do not go to last page it just stay in this page and the second frame GoBack (this continue till the second frame history finish then it change page)

**Question :**

how can i stop add back entry in main frame when second frame navigate some page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop this effect by effectively setting the JournalOwnerShip property of your navigation frame to "OwnsJournal"
The effect you experience is that the default value is set to Automatic. So when a frame will be in a NavigationWindow or another Frame, it will use the Journal of the parent meaning adding journal entries to it.
Setting it to OwnsJournal a separate Journal stack will be created for the frame in particular that has no effect on the main frame.